# Best practice for loose coupling between data & UI in Android - Adapter, Filter, CursorLoader and ContentProvider

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-adapter, android-cursorloader, android-loadermanager

Assume we have an `Activity` with `n` `TextView`s that represent one line notes. These notes are stored somewhere (local database, network etc), and each time `onResume()` being called, the proper number of `TextView`s are drawn according to that stored data.

Now, lets say the user want to delete a note, what would be the best way the resolve the specific `TextView`, back to its storage entity?

At the moment, the only way I know is by using `View.Tag`, and having some manager to translate it to data entity, but it look rather messy.

Are there any other options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Android, the `Adapter` acts a bridge between the view and the data model. You could display the ***n*** `TextViews` in either a `ListView` or a `GridView`, and when the user adds or deletes a note, the local or server database is first updated. Upon completion of the web service call and/or the local database update, the new data is added to the underlying `Adapter`. The `View` is then refreshed by calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`. This would be the way to do it.

**Approaches:**

- If updating the local `SQLite` database, you could consider using a
  [`CursorAdpater`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html)
  to hold the data for the `View`, as it directly maps the entries in
  the local database to the `View`.
- If making use of a `ContentProvider`, it is even possible to combine
  a `CursorAdapter` with a
  [`LoaderManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html)
  and a
  [`CursorLoader`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html):
  these plug into the `Activity` / `Fragment` life-cycle and monitor
  the underlying `ContentProvider` for changes that are published
  automatically to the `View` on a separate thread.
- It is also possible to use a
  [`Filter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filter.html)
  in conjunction with the `Adapter` to define a dynamic mechanism that
  sorts the data entries on-the-fly. The filtering is performed by the
  `Filter` on a separate thread, as per a query entered by the user,
  possibly in an
  [`AutoCompleteTextView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html).

**References:**

- See the [**Retrieving a List of
  Contacts**](http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html)
  tutorial. The example here retrieves a set of contacts from the
  contacts `ContentProvider` based on a dynamic, alphabetical search by
  the user. It makes use of `CursorAdapter`, `CursorLoader` and
  `LoaderManager` to monitor and update the data, and it displays the
  search results in a `ListView`.
- See also the [**Android Realtime (Instant) Search with Filter Class**](http://codetheory.in/android-filters/) example, which shows how a `Filter` is to be used.
- [**Android AutoCompleteTextView with Custom Adapter filtering**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8784249/3287204).
- [**Android AutocompleteTextView using ArrayAdapter and Filter**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10050108/3287204).