# Custom ImageView class onClick change imageResource

Tags: java, android

I've created a custom `ImageView` class, and I'm trying to change the `imageResource` when user click on it, but I'm able to call `setImageResource()` from that class.

Also I'd like to store like a second `imageView` I mean, my custom `ImageView` has the same starter `imageView` resource, but when click on it it have to be dynamic `ImageView` for instance:

ImageView1 ic_launcher (user has not clicked on it)
ImageView1 ic_user (user has clicked on it)

Can you guide how to achieve this?

This is my custom `ImageView` class :

```
public class CustomImageView extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView implements View.OnClickListener {
    private View.OnClickListener clickListener;
    public CustomImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public CustomImageView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public CustomImageView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void setOnClickListener(OnClickListener l) {
        if (l == this) {
            super.setOnClickListener(l);
        } else {
            clickListener = l;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Should change the imageResource here but also I should have to change it again if user wants (to the initial one)
        if (clickListener != null) {
            clickListener.onClick(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do You want to toggle between two images only? In that case you might use `stateListDrawable` to achieve that.

Comment: Yes but one image is always the same, the other one is dynamic

Comment: Why don't you configure the image resource from the activity or fragment which holds this `CustomImageView`?

Comment: I cannot understand, what problem when you call `setImageResource` to change the image inside `onClick`, is it warning or compile error, or it runs but the result is not as expected?

Comment: @TamHuynh I've tried `ImageView i = v; v.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);` and it works, but I want it to call from my custom class not on my `Fragment`

Comment: @ReazMurshed What do you mean? I wanted to make the code clean and each class do its work

Comment: Just use `setImageResource` or `this.setImageResource` is enough. You are using `view` in the param to call `view.setImageResource` am I right?

Comment: @TamHuynh Ya, but I'm trying to call it from an inner method so `this` does not exist, so I've created a  appCompatImageView = this; and I've done it with appCompatImageView.set.... it's ok? and what about the other stuff? Can I create a method so I can replace the current image from the old one? like toggleItAgain() or something? Also It's possible to store one ImageView inside of that class? Means default one and the user Image for instance

Comment: It's something not very clear. Are you sure `this` doesn't exist in `onClick`. In your code above, all of the methods of `CustomImageView` are instance methods, include `onClick`, there is no static method so all of them can access `this` and use any other open instance method. If this is not the right order or format, you should post all the code.

Comment: @TamHuynh I've fixed this, read my other stuff that I tould you in comment please

Comment: If you want to change the image resource regularly by changing the while `ImageView`, try `ViewFlipper`, or write your own logic and call `setImageDrawable` when you want to change image

Comment: @TamHuynh well I don't know what's better I'd like to change or flip the image whenever I want... could you put a sample to help me to see how should be my logic?

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution for a custom toggleable `ImageView`:

**Custom attribute in values/attr.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="ToggleImageView">
        <attr name="low_img" format="reference" />
        <attr name="high_img" format="reference" />
    </declare-styleable>

</resources>
```

**Custom `ImageView` class:**

```
public class ToggleImageView extends AppCompatImageView implements View.OnClickListener {
    private Drawable mLowDrawable, mHighDrawable;
    private boolean isLow = true;

    public ToggleImageView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        // Extract drawables from custom attributes
        TypedArray values = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ToggleImageView);
        setLowDrawable(values.getDrawable(R.styleable.ToggleImageView_low_img));
        setHighDrawable(values.getDrawable(R.styleable.ToggleImageView_high_img));
        values.recycle();

        setImageDrawable(mLowDrawable);

        super.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void setLowDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
        mLowDrawable = drawable;

        if (isLow)
            setImageDrawable(mLowDrawable);
    }

    public void setHighDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
        mHighDrawable = drawable;

        if (!isLow)
            setImageDrawable(mHighDrawable);
    }

    @Override
    public void setOnClickListener(@Nullable OnClickListener l) {
        // Do nothing to block setting listener from outer caller
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        toggle();
    }

    public void toggle() {
        isLow = !isLow;

        setImageDrawable(isLow ? mLowDrawable : mHighDrawable);
    }
}
```

**Usage in xml layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.example.tamhuynh.testfragment.ToggleImageView
        android:id="@+id/toggle_img"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        app:high_img="@mipmap/high_drawable"
        app:low_img="@drawable/low_drawable"
        tools:low_img="@drawable/low_drawable" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Looks good, but do you think I can call this setLow or setHigh from other class since I need this

Comment: Just edit a bit. And yes, that's why I make them public methods

Comment: i was looking for this exactly:  app:high_img="@mipmap/high_drawable"
        app:low_img="@drawable/low_drawable" thanks a lot man ;) i'm gonna test it asap but i guess it would work for sure

Comment: @StuartDTO If the code does help to solve your problem, pls mark it as answer

Comment: can you explain what this <attr name="low_img" format="reference" />
        <attr name="high_img" format="reference" /> does please? and why I have to create thetypearray?

Comment: It's the way you define and use custom attributes in your custom `View`. New attributes need to be declared in `resources` and group in a `declare-styleable` tag. This way Android knows their existence, give them ids and allow you to use them in xml layout. In the code, you have to retrieve value of custom attributes manually by the right attribute id like `R.styleable.ToggleImageView_low_img`, which is automatically created by Android. Docs is [here](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view)

Comment: And why you do this :  // Do nothing to block setting listener from outer caller

Comment: It because if somewhere in the code call `setOnClickListener` it will overrides our `super.setOnClickListener(this)` and the `onClick` method we setup won't work. Anyway, don't strictly follow what I wrote here, modify it base on your needs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172347/discussion-between-stuartdto-and-tam-huynh).

Comment: come to chat please